# Spring MVC @ModelAttribute doesn't contain submitted form results

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have an issue with form processing using Thymeleaf and Spring-MVC.
This is my view:

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container" id="containerFragment" th:fragment="containerFragment">
            <form
                action="#"
                th:action="@{/search}"
                th:object="${searchInfo}"
                method="post" >
                <fieldset id="search-query">
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        name="search"
                        value=""
                        id="search"
                        placeholder="Search for user"
                        required="required"
                        th:value="*{searchQuery}" />
                    <input
                        type="submit"
                        value="Search"
                        name="submit"
                        class="submit"/>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is my controller:

```
/** Search form */
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String search(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("searchInfo", new SearchForm());
    return "search";
}

/** Search form */
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView search(BindingResult result,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("searchInfo") SearchForm searchForm) {

    String login = searchForm.getSearchQuery();
    User user = userService.findUserByLogin(login);

    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.setViewName("search-results");
    modelAndView.addObject("user", user);

    return modelAndView;
}
```

and the search form is:

```
public class SearchForm {

    String searchQuery;

    public String getSearchQuery() {
        return searchQuery;
    }

    public void setSearchQuery(String searchQuery) {
        this.searchQuery = searchQuery;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SearchForm [searchQuery=" + searchQuery + "]";
    }
}
```

The issue is that login is null at this point of controller:

```
String login = searchForm.getSearchQuery();
```

It looks like a new SearchForm object created for POST method, but there are already one, which was created at GET step and should contains the search query.
I can't understand such behaviour.

Comment: Try to map not on FieldSet but to id="search" html tag.

Comment: Could you please be more concrete? I have no explicit mappings to FieldSet or its id or to Form tag. Form object mapped to thymeleafs "th:object" attribute. Even if I completly remove FieldSet tag I still have the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring should map HTML form attributes to your model: **SearchForm**.

Spring MVC build accordions with request parameters and your model object properties and set matching properties into your model Object before pass object into your controller method.

You named HTML property(and request parameter name automatically) as id="search". But SearchForm hasn't such property. Instead it has searchQuery [property](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/javabeans/writing/properties.html). So after Spring MVC unable to set searchQuery value into your SearchForm it pass model with *null* attribute.

Comment: You are right, problem solved. It was pretty dumb. The "name" attribute at my page should contain a "searchQuery" value. It should be the same as name Form attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Please Change th:value="*{searchQuery}" to th:field="*{searchQuery}".

I hope it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me:

FormTestController.java

```
@Controller
public class FormTestController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/form-test-1.jhtml", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String formTest1(@ModelAttribute("form1") Form1TestVO form1TestVO, Model model){
        System.out.println("You've submited: " + form1TestVO.getName())
        model.addAttribute("form1", new Form1TestVO("Form 1 test"));
        return "form-test-1";
    }

}
```

form-test-1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
    <title>Form test 1</title>
</head>
<body >

    <form th:object="${form1}" th:action="@{/form-test-1.jhtml}" >
        <input  th:field="*{name}" />
        <button>Send</button>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Form1TestVO

```
public class Form1TestVO {
    private String name;

    public Form1TestVO() {
    }

    public Form1TestVO(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

[Reference](https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/)